# JavaFX Timed transition

Tags: java, javafx

I have a number of different objects that are part of a single HBox that I want to move to certain positions. I have managed to do this using ParallelTransition, and it works pretty good. However I'd like to have these different objects move one by one, and not all at the same time.

I've looked into Timelines, however these are only compatible with KeyFrames which I believe cannot contain ParallelTransition objects.

How can I get the different objects of my pane to move one by one and not all together at the same time?

Comment: Post your code here so it'll be easier to assist you.

Comment: @JakeMiller I'd rather not post my code online, I was just looking for some general advice on what I should look into to achieve what I want

Comment: You need sequential transition.